# use of . in bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

scriptdir="$HOME"
touch $scriptdir/foo.txt
. "$scriptdir/foo.txt" ||
{ echo "Missing '$scriptdir/foo.txt'. Exiting." ;
exit 1 ;}
echo "$scriptdir/foo.txt is present"
echo
rm "$scriptdir/foo.txt"
. "$scriptdir/foo.txt" ||
{ echo "Missing '$scriptdir/foo.txt'. Exiting." ;
exit 1 ;}
```

I don't understand the use of `.` in `. "$scriptdir/foo.txt" ||`

It seems to be functioning similar to `if [ -f "$scriptdir/foo.txt ]` , yes?

Such that

```
scriptdir="$HOME"
touch $scriptdir/foo.txt
 if [ -f "$scriptdir/foo.txt" ] ; then
   echo
 else
 { echo "Missing '$scriptdir/foo.txt'. Exiting." ;
exit 1 ;}
 fi
```

yields a similar result.

Can someone elaborate on the use of `.` here?

If I write a script in foo.txt then that script will presumably run because `.` causes a file to execute rather than just looking to see if it is there? And, as long as `$scriptdir/foo.txt` is present and executable, then the right half of `||` will never run because the left half is returning an exit status of zero?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between '.' and 'source' in shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/58514)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is a bash built-in, same as `source`, what it does is that it reads and executes commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  Type `help .` or `help source` in your terminal to check out it's full documentation.
Full documentation:

```
.: . filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

Comment: Ok. So, if I write a script in foo.txt then that script will presumably run because `.` causes a file to execute rather than just looking to see if it is there? And as long as `$scriptdir/foo.txt` is present and executable then the right half of `||` will never run because the left half is returning an exit status of zero? @David Dai

Comment: yes, if the file contains commands, these commands will execute.  as stated in the document, `.` returns the status of the LAST command executed in the file, if the last command of the file returns a non-zero the command after `||` will run. @Bleakley

Comment: Hmmm. So I can enter a script that ends with `false` into `$scriptdir/foo.txt` causing it to exit nonzero and therefore `||` will evaluate the right side. Interesting... Thanks! @Dave Dai

Comment: Thanks @JuliePelletier. It is acting the way I want but it seems the echo message on the right side of `||` is technically incorrect if the `foo.txt` exits nonzero.

Comment: @JuliePelletier `&&` will not force both to run, instead the latter command will run if and only if the command in front of  `&&` returns 0 (true)